# how to call execute onPressed only one conditions is met

Tags: flutter

Need to call **play()** when **onPressed** but play button need to show only after recording is complete.

```
Expanded(
              child: GestureDetector(
                child: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
                    color: Colors.white,
                    iconSize: 50,
                    onPressed: (){
                      play();
                    }),
```

need to check this `isComplete && recordFilePath != null` before showing the play button, How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with ternary operators by showing a `SizedBox()` when the conditions are not met.

```dart
   isComplete && recordFilePath != null ? Expanded(
      child: GestureDetector(
        child: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
          color: Colors.white,
          iconSize: 50,
          onPressed: () => play(),
        ),
      ),
    ) : SizedBox(),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operators to check if the condition is met or not:

If the condition is met(i.e true), show the play button.
If the condition is not met(i.e false), show an empty widget[that doesn't take up space).

I added a demo using your code as an example:

```
 (isComplete && recordFilePath != null)
            // show the play button if the condition is met
                ? Expanded(
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      child: IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
                          color: Colors.white,
                          iconSize: 50,
                          onPressed: () {
                            play();
                          }),
                    ),
                  )
                  // show a shrinked sized box if the condition isn't met
                : SizedBox.shrink(),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operators

```
return isComplete && recordFilePath != null
        ? Expanded(
            child: GestureDetector(
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
                color: Colors.white,
                iconSize: 50,
                onPressed: () {
                  play();
                },
              ),
            ),
          )
        : SizedBox();
```